# PHP imagepng File Output Works, But Show Blank On Browser

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
public function generateImage ($product_path, $layer1_path, $layer2_path, $result_path, $price) {

    $product = imagecreatefromjpeg($product_path);

    $dest = imagecreatefrompng($layer1_path);
    $src = imagecreatefrompng($layer2_path);

    imagecopymerge($dest, $product, 560, 67, 0, 0, 574, 494, 100);
    imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 400, 170, 0, 0, 220, 220, 100);

    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($dest, $result_path);

    imagedestroy($dest);
    imagedestroy($src);

    return $result_path;

}
```

when I run that code, it gives this on my browser : [image]

the output file is actually exist on path that I wanted. but instead of giving this black screen, I need `$result_path` as an output.

how to get the path, not this black screen? thank you.

Comment: Are you `echo`ing the generated image anywhere?

Comment: `$socmed = new SocialMedia();
$socmed-> generateImage ($product_path, $fb_layer1_path, $layer2_path, $fb_card_path, $price);
`

Comment: I'm not `echo` ing the result.

Comment: Then there's your problem. You're generating an image, and then **not** sending it to the browser.

Comment: what if I just want to save the image file and just get the path? is it possible?

Comment: Sure. But then you shouldn't call `header('Content-Type: image/png');` -- that tells the browser to expect an image.

Comment: IT WORKS, BRO!!! thank you so much for your help... wow! you're the best!